# android studioのlayout editorで画面を設計するときの、親画面の横幅・高さ

Tags: android

android studioのlayout editorで画面を設計するときの、画面の横幅・高さの大きさは何dpですか。それは、どこで定義されているのですか。
サンプル　プログラムでは、fillになっていて、なんとなくもやもやします。

Answer (score 0):

> android studioのlayout editorで画面を設計するときの、画面の横幅・高さの大きさは何dpですか。それは、どこで定義されているのですか。

Android Studio に限らず Android で画面設計時に何DPを想定して画面デザインをするべきか、という質問でよろしいでしょうか？

こちらは特に決まっていません。開発しているアプリケーションのターゲットデバイスに応じてあらゆる画面サイズに対応することとなります。デバイスは縦長画面かもしれませんし、横長画面かもしれませんし、正方形かもしれません。また縦長画面であっても画面分割時には横長や正方形に近いアスペクト比になります。そのため一般的にDP指定であっても位置固定でのレイアウトは望まれません。(特定端末向けの業務アプリケーションなどは別ですが)

Android の開発者向けドキュメントなどを参照してください。

- https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support?hl=JA - 画面互換性の概要
- https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes?hl=JA - さまざまな画面サイズをサポートする